# Shell program which reads line and output lines with the line numbers

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to write a program that reads lines from a file on `stdin` and writes the lines to `stdout` with line numbers. I cannot use `cat -n`.

Let's say the text file had this:

```
 abcdef
 ghi

 klm
 nopqr st
```

It should basically read those lines and output those lines but with lines numbers.

This is the while read loop I have but it doesn't print out every line.

```
while read line
do
    awk '{print NR, $0}'

done < file
```

Basically what this output is this:

```
1 ghi
2 
3 klm
4 nopqr   st
```

For some reason the `abcdef` doesn't show up and number 2 isn't supposed to be blank.

Comment: You don't need the loop, Awk can handle this: `awk '{print NR, $0}' file`...

Comment: yeah but one line is just blank

Comment: what's wrong with `cat -n`?

Comment: forgot to mention the question said dont use "cat -n"

Comment: You didn't specify that you want to remove blank lines...

Comment: Use `nl` then. ;)

Comment: @cas and since this -is-that-a-forwarded-homework-question said to not use `cat -n` that would of course not work. maybe the presumable homework was though as a shell programming thing and existing gnu coreutils would make it too easy. maybe even `nl` is disallowed ;)

Comment: The input has a blank line, the output has a blank line in the same place. All is good.

Comment: Is it homework?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried `nl -b a <file_name>`

```
debian@virt00:~/test$ nl -b a file
     1  abcdef
     2   ghi
     3
     4   klm
     5   nopqr st
debian@virt00:~/test$
```

- nl stands for number line
- -b flag for body numbering
- 'a' for all lines.

for more information http://linux.die.net/man/1/nl

Answer (score 3):

You may use "cat -n", flag "-n" is to add the numbers to the output lines of "cat".

Comment: Edited the main question, can't use "cat -n"

Comment: Then use '''( let n=0; while read line; do echo "$n $line"; let n++; done )'''

Comment: @shawnedward if the reason not to used `cat -n` are the empy lines then delete them first `sed "/^$/d" | cat -n`

Comment: And also there is "-b" flag for "cat"...

Comment: and last but not least `cat -n |   sed -e '/^[ \t0-9]*$/d'` would include empty lines in numbering yet not print those lines (which would be a `cat --number-all-only-show-nonblank` of sorts)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$0!=""{print NR, $0}' file
```

The `$0 != ""` means `$0` `not equal` to empty. For those lines print line number and line.

---

That will produce this output:

```
1 abcdef
2 ghi
4 klm
5 nopqr st
```

with the old line numbers. If you need the output with the new line numbers:

```
awk '$0!=""{a++; print a, $0}' file
```

---

```
1 abcdef
2 ghi
3 klm
4 nopqr st
```

---

To explain how your script worked:

The line with `read line` will read the first line (you do not print it).
Then, you connect the file to `awk` and it process all the other lines.
Awk does not (by default) obviate empty lines, so the empty line is also printed.

There are many ways to solve this, the one above seems as simple as is possible.

Comment: Upvoted for explanation of what was wrong with OP's attempt.

Comment: fyi, your awk example can be simplified to `awk '!!$0{ print ++a,$0; }'`

Comment: @DarkHeart Of course, you are right. Trying to be KISS. :-) ..... Of course, note that this also works: `awk '$0{print ++a, $0}' file`.

Comment: `awk NF` is the usual idiom for non-blank lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '!/^$/{print ++a, $0}' file

echo

awk '!!$0{print ++a, $0}' file

echo

awk '{if ($0 != "") print ++aa, $0}' file

echo

NR=0
while read -r
do
    [[ "${REPLY}" = "" ]] || echo $((++NR)) "${REPLY}"
done < file

echo
```